# Site is slow due to multi store

Tags: magento2

We have a Magento 2 (v 2.2.4) site where 17 multi store is configured. In recent days we observed that the site is performing slow. We tested the whole site in test lab and found that after removing all multi store the site is super fast.

We checked in everywhere that might cause problem for multi store but did not find a clue.

Could you please help?

Comment: Did you try flat tables on in the back office?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We did not use that.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Yes implemented it. But does not work.